# What does $dzd\bar{z}$ mean?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

I've seen people write $g(z) = dzd\bar{z}$ to refer to the standard conformal metric on the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ (e.g., on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_geometry#Euclidean_space)). I thought this was referring to the tensor product $dz \otimes d\bar{z}$, but $dz \otimes d\overline{z}$ is a Hermitian metric and not a Riemannian metric (in particular, it is not real-valued). The Wikipedia page linked earlier defines a conformal metric as a Riemannian metric. Am I missing something?

Edit: To clarify, here is what I was thinking when I said $dz \otimes d\bar{z}$ is Hermitian:
$$
(dx + idy) \otimes (dx - idy) = dx \otimes dx + dy \otimes dy + i(dy \otimes dx - dx \otimes dy).
$$
As tensors, $dy \otimes dx$ and $dx \otimes dy$ are distinct, e.g. $(dy \otimes dx)(\partial / \partial y, \partial / \partial x) = 1$ but $(dx \otimes dy)(\partial / \partial y, \partial / \partial x) = 0$.

Comment: I think it's just the Euclidean metric with $\overline{z}$ the complex conjugate of $z$.

Comment: I suggest you try figuring this out by writing everything out in turns of $x$ and $y$ and using the basic properties of the tensor product. Separate the real terms from the imaginary ones. If you get stuck, just post what you have and we can guide you from there.

Comment: $dz\,d\overline{z}=dz\,\overline{dz}=(dx+idy)(dx-idy)=(dx)^2+(dy)^2$ looks very Riemannian to me.

Comment: @KurtG. Then you can’t be interpreting this as a tensor product right? Otherwise $dx$ and $dy$ don’t commute. The way I’m seeing it is $dz \otimes d\bar{z}$ is simply the inner product $\langle z, w\rangle = z\bar{w}$, which is a Hermitian inner product.

Comment: Generally when one writes $dx_idx_j$ they are referring to a symmetric tensor product, as in $dx_i\otimes dx_j+dx_j\otimes dx_i$

Comment: @Chris Ohh, I see that makes much more sense now. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris, that's not right. In this case, it really is the tensor product. The symbol $\otimes$ is never used to mean the symmetric tensor product. The symbol $\circ$ sometimes is.

Comment: \begin{align*} dz\otimes d\bar{z} &= (dx+idy)\otimes (dx-idy)\\ &= dx\otimes dx + i\,dy\otimes dx - i\,dx\otimes dy + dy\otimes dy\\ &= (dx\otimes dx + dy\otimes dy) - i(dx\otimes dy - dy\otimes dx)\\ &= g - i\omega, \end{align*} where $g = dx\otimes dx + dy\otimes dy$ is a symmetric $2$-tensor called the flat metric and $\omega = dz\wedge d\bar{z}$ is a $2$-form that is a scalar multiple of the Kahler form.

Comment: @Deane I didn't mean that $\otimes$ is used to write the symmetric tensor product, I meant that in the literature, one often writes $g_{ij}dx^idx^j$ to mean:
\begin{align}
g_{ij}dx^idx^j=g_{ij}\frac{1}{2}(dx^i\otimes dx^j+dx^j\otimes dx^i)
\end{align}
I am pretty sure this is equivalent to writin $g_{ij}dx^i\otimes dx^j$

Comment: @Chris, I apologize. I did not read your comment carefully enough. I think that indeed some people assume that $dx\,dy = dy\,dx$. But, as you point out, when you write $g_{ij}\,dx^i\,dx^j$, it doesn't matter whether $dx^i\,dx^j$ is the tensor product or the symmetric tensor product. These days, I avoid the symmetric tensor product.